# Unable to execute SQL Server stored procedure with variables (could not find stored procedure)

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I was unable to find the solution for the issue and unable to execute a stored procedure. Am I missing anything in the stored procedure?

Main aim is to run multiple tables inserts into different tables (different metadata).

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE newsample
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sqlquery varchar(max);
    SET @sqlquery = 'insert into dbo.table1 select 2 as newcol;
                     insert into dbo.table2 select 2 as newcol;
                     insert into dbo.table3 select 2 as newcol;
                     insert into dbo.table4 select 2 as newcol;';
    EXEC @sqlquery 
END

EXEC dbo.newsample
```

Error:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure dbo.newsample, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 9]
> Could not find stored procedure 'insert into dbo.table1  select 2 as newcol'.

Appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: Why even bother trying to use dynamic SQL here?? Makes absolutely no sense..... just write the four `INSERT` statements as is and run the procedure.....

Comment: I have 150 tables inserts with different metadata. mainly i need to parameterize few values . if it is working then i will add more conditions

Comment: Without a batch separator (GO) in the appropriate spot, your last statement which attempts to execute your procedure is actually INSIDE your procedure. And there are two forms of the EXECUTE statement - you are using the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

To execute arbitrary dynamic sql, you have to use `exec()`, not `exec`.

```
exec('select 0'); exec(@myDynamicSql);
```

If you use `exec arg`, then arg is a stored procedure or function, or the name of a stored procedure or function. Yep, it can be a function. And these can either be the literal names, or strings with the value of the name. All of the following works:

```
create procedure dbo.p as begin set nocount on; end;
go
create function dbo.funcwithoutargs() returns int as begin return 2; end
go
create function dbo.funcwithargs(@i int) returns int as begin return @i; end
go
declare @i int = 0, @module sysname;
exec dbo.p;
exec @i = dbo.funcwithoutargs;
exec @i = dbo.funcwithargs @i;
set @Module = 'dbo.p';
exec @module;
set @module = 'dbo.funcwithoutargs';
exec @i = @module;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
EXEC @sqlquery
```

Should be

```
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @sqlquery
```